# Ubuntu Server 11.10 64bit - FTP

Tags: 11.10, server, ssh, sftp

I am new to Linux as due to a requirement at work we are trailing Splunk which runs better un Linux. So I have installed Ubuntu Server 11.10 and put it in the DC with SSH access.

However, I have since realized that really I also need transfer files and folders to the server and as such need to work out the best way to do this. I also need to bear in mind there is not internet connectivity to the server and firewall(s) are blocking all ports except 22, although could request for more to be opened if needed.

From my understanding you can not transfer files via SSH itself over port 22? Does the server need setting up as an FTP server to be able to receive files? If it does need to be setup as an FTP server are there any in-built to the O/S?

Many thanks for the input and help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transfer files across SSH - this should work out of the box with the default install of openssh-server on Ubuntu Server. You don't say what client you are using for SSH access, so here are a selection of clients that can do SCP / SFTP.

- `pscp`, the SCP utility that is part of the [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) suite
- [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/), using sftp:// urls
- Nautilus (the default file manager in GNOME / Ubuntu)
- The `scp` utility from the openssh suite (as part of [Cygwin](http://filezilla-project.org/) or a Linux installation)

You may have to transfer the files to your home folder on the server if your user does not own the target folder (e.g. `/var/www`), then move/copy them from there using `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenSSH server should be able to handle file transfers. If you are on a linux client, just use `scp` to transfer files to and from the machine.